# random width assembly of three images in a row

Tags: javascript, image, random, responsive-design, width

i want to put three images in an order. All **together** must have the full width of the browser window ( width: 100%), but every single image have to had a random width for itself. This should generate new by random with every reload.

Can someone help me?

Thx a lot

Comment: do you ask community to write code for you?

Comment: Show us what you tried so far?

Comment: Probably you want to hire a developer: http://careers.stackoverflow.com/ ;)

Comment: @SebastianG : LOL :D That was a good one :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have to got some min and max width;

Something like this would work

```
var cell1 = randomNum(20,40);
var cell2 = randomNum(20,40);
var cell3 = 100 - cell1 - cell2;

function randomNum (min, max) {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
}
```

This will give you percents that combined makes 100